# AfxMessageBox shows up in the middle of the desktop

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I call AfxMessageBox() function expecting the pop-up to be centered to the MFC dialog that called it. However the box gets centered to the desktop rather than to the dialog. Its position doesn't depend on actual location of the parent dialog. What can cause such behavior? Is it possible to move AfxMessageBox to a desired position? Thanks!

Comment: `CWinApp` gives you an opportunity to tweak the behaviour of `AfxMessageBox` via the virtual function `DoMessageBox`. So if you establish who has the focus, you can determine the associated top-level window and use that when you call `MessageBox`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
int WINAPI MessageBox(
  _In_opt_  HWND hWnd,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpText,
  _In_opt_  LPCTSTR lpCaption,
  _In_      UINT uType
);
```

and pass the handle of the application window as first parameter (HWND). Then it should be centered.

I don't use MFC anymore, but I think the main application window must be set somewhere (InitInstance?), maybe if this is not done, AfxMessageBox doesn't use the application window.

Answer (score 0):

A dialog box can be centered on its parent window. AfxMessageBox is created as a 'system wide' dialog box, meaning not a 'child' dialog box of your application window, and that is why it is not centered on your parent window, but on the desktop.

You wont be able to move AfxMessageBox after its creation, since it is a modal dialog box (and the hassle of creating a thread just in order to move the dialog, is probably not worth it).

The better solution would be just to create your own dialog function (as suggested above by alain). Then, when you call it, you can pass the window handle of your calling window class (hWnd) and the dialog created will be centered on your application window, as you wanted.